# Implementing saml based SSO with WSO2 identity server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, wso2

I am unable to implement Saml SSO with WSO2 identity server 5.11 and trying sending multiple request all the request, responses and urls are mentioned below.

URL : https://10.100.144.92:9443/samlsso

Xml Request :

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest 
       xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" " +
      "xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
      ID=""+"_"+ Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+ "" " +
      "Version="2.0" IssueInstant="" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "" " +
      "AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://10.16.69.102:44327/IdPInitiated/ResponseInitiate%5C"> " +
     "<saml:Issuer>efbr</saml:Issuer></samlp:AuthnRequest>"
```

2nd request

URL 1:

```
https://10.100.144.92:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fsamlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=7d6be073-43a6-4e5e-ad4d-c7872dd1969a&relyingParty=efbr&type=samlsso&sp=efbr&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator%3ALOCAL
```

URL 2 :

```
https://10.100.144.92:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do
```

3rd Request

URL 1 : https://10.100.144.92:9443/logincontext

I really need help in this the issue is 2nd and 3rd request I am receiving in response the url in which I am send the request, please guide me in this.